# Count the number of matched element in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to count the number of elements which correspond to one arbitrary value in Python and pandas with respect to each group?

I mean the following code in R and plyr:

```
ddply(df, .(group), summarise, x=sum(ifelse(y==1, 1, 0)))
```

So, what do I have to write out the following missing part?

```
df.groupby(["groupA", "groupB"]).apply(lambda x: ....?)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by conditionally matched exactly?

Comment: You looking for count? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple sum of all 1, then:

```
df.groupby(["groupA", "groupB"]).sum()
```

IF you want to use condition:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x[x['B'] > 0]['B'].sum())
```

or

```
df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: np.sum(x[x > 0]))
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aaabbbbccc'), 'B':[1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})
>>> df.groupby('A').sum()
   B
A   
a  2
b  2
c  1
>>> df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x[x['B'] > 0]['B'].sum())
A
a    2
b    2
c    1
>>> df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: np.sum(x[x > 0]))
     B
A     
a  2
b  2
c  1
```

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like I shouldn't have used numerical elements (such as `1` or `0`). Your solution may work well in numerical values, but doesn't work in strings - for example, `df.groupby("A").apply(lambda x: x[x["state"] == "CA"]["state"].sum()` returns `CACACACACACACACA...`, not the total number of occurrence of `CA` with respect to each group.

Comment: You right, it's better to use size - I'll add solution a bit later

Comment: Ah, OK, changed `sum()` function to `count()` function (`df.groupby("A").apply(lambda x: x[x["state"] == "CA"]["state"].count()`) and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of R and plyr. Hope following would help you to count by grouping `DataFrame` columns.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby(["groupA","groupB"]).size()}).reset_index()
```

And further you can sort them.

```
df2.sort_index(by=['count'], ascending=False)
```